# Trouble in getting response through odoo server through xml-Rpc in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, odoo, xml-rpc

**Client side App code**

```
XMLRPCRequest *request=[[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:server_url]];

    NSArray *param=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"demoDB",user_id,password, nil];

    [request setMethod:@"user_data" withParameters:param];


XMLRPCConnectionManager *manager = [XMLRPCConnectionManager sharedManager];

XMLRPCResponse *response=[XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request error:nil ];

    NSString* result = [response body];

    NSLog(@"%@",result);

    if ([response faultCode]==0)

    {

        NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:result];

        NSLog(@"%@",xmlDoc);

    }else

    {

        NSString* error = @"error";

        NSLog(@"%@",error);

    }
```

**Server side PHP code**

```
$url = "http://www.someurl.com:8069";

$db = "demoDB";

$email = "someid@---";

$password = "******";

require_once('ripcord-1.1/ripcord.php');

$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");

$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $email, $password, array());

$models = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/object");

if ($uid) {
    #first load username
    $user_data = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
        'res.users', 'read',
        array($uid),
        array('fields'=>array('name', 'company_id')));

} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: If you could post your code (from both client and server side) would be helpful

Comment: can you please give me your mail id

Comment: I don't know O-C so I don't think I can help you, but other people could. That's why I suggested you to post your code. If there are problems about sharing it, you could try to modify it a little, but without knowing what are you exactly doing, is hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example may it helpful for you

SOAP webservice calling in iOS with xml parsing
http://www.jogendra.com/2015/03/soap-webservice-calling-in-ios-with-xml.html

Comment: @Vivek check again